# How to style text similar to a business card?

Tags: css, styling

I need to design something similar to a business card as following:

```
My Businesses
Logo  AAA                                              Logo  BBB
      93939393                                               87878787
      10 sample road, city                                   15 new lane, city
We are the best, contact us for more information.      This is another business
We are always here to help.                            It is always here to help.
                                         Link1                                Link2

Other entries go the same.
```

As you can see it has a logo that is image, then business name goes in front of it, next line is phone, next line address and the following lines are the description of the business. At the end, the last line is a link to the website of the business.

**Code**

```css
    .test {
      clear: both;
      display: block;
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 90%;
      height: 100%;
      max-width: 1400px;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .test ul li {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      height: 240px;
      width: 24%;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid orange;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 8px;
      margin: 4px;
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="test">
<h2>My Businesses</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="" width="100" height="100" />
      <p>AAA
        <br/>93939393
        <br/>10 sample road, city
        <br/>We are the best, contact us for more information. We are always here to help.</br>
        Link1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="" width="100" height="100" />
      <p>BBB
        <br/>87878787
        <br/>15 new lane, city
        <br/>This is another business It is always here to help.</br>
        Link2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="" width="100" height="100" />
      <p>CCC
        <br/>12121212
        <br/>34 alex avenue, city
        <br/>This is the third business. They are also there to help.</br>
        Link3</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Current code made it like this

```css
    .test {
      clear: both;
      display: block;
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 90%;
      height: 100%;
      max-width: 1400px;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .test ul li {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      height: 240px;
      width: 24%;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid orange;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 8px;
      margin: 4px;
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="test">
<h2>My Businesses</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="" width="100" height="100" />
      <p>AAA
        <br/>93939393
        <br/>10 sample road, city
        <br/>We are the best, contact us for more information. We are always here to help.</br>
        Link1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="" width="100" height="100" />
      <p>BBB
        <br/>87878787
        <br/>15 new lane, city
        <br/>This is another business It is always here to help.</br>
        Link2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="" width="100" height="100" />
      <p>CCC
        <br/>12121212
        <br/>34 alex avenue, city
        <br/>This is the third business. They are also there to help.</br>
        Link3</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
        Logo  
         AAA
         93939393
    10 sample road, city We are the best, contact us 
   for more information.We are always here to help.
          Link
```

Comment: let me know why you voted negative!!!

Comment: For who needs it http://jsbin.com/qovasa/2/edit

Comment: In your 'responsive' design it'll be hard to get it right for all *media* (as currently your questions stands.)

Comment: Also you have in your code `text-align: center;` but you clearly don't need it... Can you show your best try to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qovasa/7/)***

Here's a new sample of the needed HTML markup inside your LI element:

```
<p>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100&text=LOGO" width="100" height="100"/>
    AAA<br/>
    93939393<br/>
    10 sample road, city
</p>
<p>
    We are the best, contact us for more information.
    We are always here to help.</br>
    Link1
</p>
```

CSS:

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0; } /* GUR Global Ugly Reset */

.test ul {
  text-align:center;
}

.test ul li{
  text-align:left;
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 24%;
  border: 1px solid orange ;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.test li p{overflow: hidden; margin: 10px;}
.test p + p{clear: both;}
.test li p img{float: left; margin-right:10px;}
```

Comment: great thanks, the only problem is that I need them to be in the center of the window. With the code you provided, they started from left and end at the right of the window.

Comment: I changed the width to 15% (width: 15%;) but the header is still on the left.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the title, I just added that.

Comment: Thanks, sorry but I forgot to add the title, I just added that, and need that to be on the top of the main box as shown in the question. Another thing is that how to put the links on the right side of the box not left as they are now? thanks buddy.

Comment: I could just solve the problem of links. You may see "My Businesses" title added to the expected result.

Comment: Buddy the problem is that I have just one title for the whole section thats why I do not know what to do with that.

Comment: should be able to see that now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65791/discussion-between-jack-and-roko-c-buljan).